# Loops thru current array of hashes; build a new array of hashes and ignore records with certain key = value

Tags: perl

I have $arr with many records, but i only showed 2 records here for simplicity:

```
$arr = [
     {
       'a' => 1,
       'b' => 2,
       'c' => 'failed'
     },
     {
       'a' => 5,
       'b' => 6,
       'c' => 'success'
    },
    {...}, {...}, {...}
    ];
```

I want to loop thru $arr above and ignore any record with 'c'='success' and put in a new $newarr; or it's ok to overwrite $arr instead of creating a new $newarr.

```
$newarr = [
     {
       'a' => 1,
       'b' => 2,
       'c' => 'failed'
     }
];
```

Comment: [grep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) is your friend

Comment: I've been trying. They only showed how to loop thru and search and print certain key=value.

Comment: Try this: `my $newarr = [ grep { !( exists $_->{c} and $_->{c} eq 'success') } @$arr ]`

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much. @HåkonHægland

Comment: Much like in the accepted answer, that leaves some elements in `$newarr` and `$arr` as _references to same data_, so it leaves you with a bug: for some changes in `$arr` the `$newarr` is changed, and the other way round. Instead, you'd needa deep copy, or  `@$arr =  grep {  ... } @$arr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `grep` should achieve this:

- `@{}` to de-reference the array ref
- `grep {}` to apply a filter on the resulting list
- `$_->{c] ne 'success'` the filter that should be applied to each element
- `grep` aliases `$_` to each element in the list: in your case each list element is a hash ref
- `$->{c}` de-reference the hash ref to retrieve the value for key `c`
- **NOTE:** this is a shallow copy approach, i.e. `@{ $arr }` and `@new` contain references to the same hash refs.

For details see [perlfunc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $arr = [
    {
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 'failed',
    },
    {
        'a' => 5,
        'b' => 6,
        'c' => 'success',
    },
];

my @new = grep { $_->{c} ne 'success' } @{ $arr };

print Dumper(\@new);

exit 0;
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'c' => 'failed',
            'b' => 2,
            'a' => 1
          }
        ];
```

Comment: "_The elements won't be recreated_" -- correct, but that's a bug: If a value is changed in `$arr` then `@new` may get changed, and vice versa.

Comment: @zdim that's why I pointed it out to the OP so that he is aware of it.

Comment: Sure, but there is nothing one can do about it once it's there; just can't work with these any more.  However, I think that `@$arr = grep ... @$arr` takes care of it? The OP says that overwriting is fine. (One can also mention a deep copy, with say `dclone`.)